# Python pygame movement question about classes

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to implement movement from my enemy class to follow the player class. Currently, the enemy class only moves in a straight line to the left. Here is some code to better understand my question.

Here is the player class

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 40))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = 25
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT / 2
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0
```

Here is the enemy class

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self2):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self2)
        self2.image = pygame.Surface((50, 40))
        self2.image.fill(RED)
        self2.rect = self2.image.get_rect()
        self2.rect.x = random.randrange(680, 750)
        self2.rect.y = random.randrange(HEIGHT - self2.rect.height)
        self2.speedx = random.randrange(-5, -3)
        self2.speedy = random.randrange(-5, 5)
        self2.min_dist = 200

    def update(self2):
        self2.speedy = 0
        self2.rect.x += self2.speedx
        self2.rect.y += self2.speedy
        if self2.rect.left < -25 or self2.rect.top < -25 or self2.rect.bottom > HEIGHT + 10:
            self2.rect.x = random.randrange(680, 750)
            self2.rect.y = random.randrange(HEIGHT - self2.rect.height)
            self2.speedx = random.randrange(-5, -3)

    def move_towards_Player(self2, Player):
        delta_x = Player.rect.x - self2.rect.x
        delta_y = Player.rect.y - self2.rect.y
        if abs(delta_x) <= self2.min_dist and abs(delta_y) <= self2.min_dist:
            enemy_move_x = abs(delta_x) > abs(delta_y)
        if abs(delta_x) > self2.speedx and abs(delta_x) > self2.speedx:
            enemy_move_x = random.random() < 0.5
        if enemy_move_x:
            self2.rect.x += min(delta_x, self2.speedx) if delta_x > 0 else max(delta_x, -self2.speedx)
        else:
            self2.rect.y += min(delta_y, self2.speedy) if delta_y > 0 else max(delta_y, -self2.speedy)
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)

for i in range(3):
    e = Enemy()
    all_sprites.add(e)
    enemies.add(e)

running = True
while running:

    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    all_sprites.update()
    #Draw render
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Sorry for the large post in code just would like to get the best answer for this.

Question 1) This is probably a very simple question but, how come when the all_sprites.Group get updated in the loop why doesn't the move_towards player get updated?

Question 2) I tried letting the update inherit Player, like this

```
def update(self2, Player):
```

why doesn't this work?

Question 3) How can I make the move_towards_Player get updated in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

> how come when the all_sprites.Group get updated in the loop why doesn't the move_towards player get updated?

You ask why the `move_towards_Player` function is not called? Because you never call it, and it isn't magically called by anything. The `update` function of `Group` will call the `update` function of all its sprites. Nothing more.

> I tried letting the update inherit Player, like this ... why doesn't this work?

The `update` function of `Group` will pass all arguments to the `update` function of all its sprites. So you could call it like this:

```
all_sprites.update(player)
```

and ensure that all sprite classes have their `update` function take an extra argument beside `self`.

> How can I make the move_towards_Player get updated in the loop?

Just call it from the Enemy's `update` function.

You could start with something like this:

```
import pygame
import random
GREEN=(0,255,0)
RED=(255,0,0)
BLACK=(0,0,0)
HEIGHT=600
WIDTH=800
FPS=120

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 40))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = 25
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT / 2
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, target):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 40))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(680, 750)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(HEIGHT - self.rect.height)
        self.target = target
        self.speed = random.randint(4, 6)

    def update(self, dt):
        self.move_towards_Player(dt)

    def move_towards_Player(self, dt):
        pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.center)
        v = pygame.Vector2(self.target.rect.center) - pos
        if (v.length() < 5):
            self.kill()
        else:
            v.normalize_ip()
            v *= self.speed * dt/10
            pos += v
            self.rect.center = round(pos.x), round(pos.y)

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)

for i in range(3):
    e = Enemy(player)
    all_sprites.add(e)
    enemies.add(e)
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode([WIDTH, HEIGHT])
running = True
while running:

    dt=clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    all_sprites.update(dt)
    #Draw render
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Note that:

- I renamed `self2` to `self`. By convention, the first argument of a method should be called `self`. Stick to it.
- I pass the `Player` instance to the `Enemy`-class' `__init__` function and store it in a class member. This way, we don't have to "pollute" the `update` function
- I use pygame's `Vector2` class to handle the math.
- I pass the delta time to the update function so the movement speed is constant even when the framerate is not